# Is a superposed state ever actually measured as such , since upon measurement the wavefunction is supposed to collapse to one od its eigenstates?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

...or is it that the superposed wavefunction is useful in that it provides the right density of probability but that no matter what the cat is never actually measured both dead AND alive !
Thanks for your help.

Comment: We don't (and can't) measure states *at all*. We measure *observables*. To predict the probabilities for the possible measurement outcomes for the *observed values* correctly, we describe the system pre-measurement with (possibly) superimposed states.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Please let me reformulate my question. Since the measured value has to be one of the eigenvalues of the operator and the wave function collapses into the associated eigenfunction, is it correct to say that a superposed state is needed to obtain the correct probability density but has no physical meaning per say : in other word is it correct to say that the cat is never measured both dead and alive ? If so, then why such fuss about superposed states in general and Schrody's cat in particular. Are they not just a mathematical trick to obtain the correct results ?

Comment: In order to attract proper answers instead of comments, please edit your reformulation into the question itself.

Comment: Indeed it is correct to say that "the cat" is never measured to be both alive and dead, which is part of the point of the original thought experiment. But I'm not sure what to say about quantum states being "just a mathematical trick to obtain correct results". Consider a classical particle travelling in a straight line. Is a set of linear parametric equations for $x,y,z$, or a vector-valued position-as-function-of-time "just a mathematical trick" to describe the motion?

Comment: And remember, in quantum mechanics the *state* is the thing that evolves with time under a given Hamiltonian (in the Schrödinger picture), and this evolution is given by the *non-classical* Schrödinger equation. Is this also "just a mathematical trick"? I personally don't think so.

Comment: Thank you for your comments Marius. We sometimes read that the wavefunction has no physical meaning other that the density of probability we can derive from it. What do you think ?

Comment: I think it is misleading, because the truth is more subtle. Yes, it is true that we can never measure the values of the wave function (given it takes generally complex values). But on the other hand, we have examples like the [Aharonov-Bohm effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aharonov%E2%80%93Bohm_effect) where there is a coupling between an electromagnetic potential and the *complex phase of the wave function*, and this complex phase vanishes if we go to the probability density. So the wave function has real, measurable, physical *effects*.

Comment: Interesting ! But what do you mean by " if we go to the probability density" ? Thanks.

Comment: I mean that we cannot describe the Aharonov-Bohm effect by only talking about the probability density, we actually need the wave function itself. This is because when you use the wave function to derive the corresponding probability density, the complex phase of the wave function disappears from the mathematical expression for the density, and it is this complex phase that the electromagnetic potential couples to. So if we think that the probability density is the only thing with physical meaning, then we lose the information about the aforementioned coupling.

Comment: Thank you again. One last question if I may (feel free not to answer or redirect me to books references Do the following three terms refer to the same thing : quantum field (associated to a particle e.g. Higgs boson) vs wave function vs wave ( as in the duality wave particle) ? Thanks !